# How generate maximum hits/s

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, blazemeter

I have recorder a simple flow using jmeter. I have multiple http requests under one thread group. I am trying to run this thread group for 50 concurrent users in blazemeter. But when ever i try to run the jmx file i can see that htis/s is around 3 sec. Though my rampup time is 0 & thread is 50. My understanding is if the users are concurrent & each user (thread) have 3 requests to make, then minimum hits/s should be 50.

I have added a constant throughput timer at the bottom of the thread group & a throughput controller. In the timer target throughput is set to 300 & in the throughput controller throughput is set to 100 with percent execution.

How do i achieve maximum hits/s in blazemeter? Or am i missing something here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're misusing Constant Throughput Timer.

1. Throughput of 300 requests per minute gives 300/60 = **5 requests per second**
2. Constant Throughput Timer works on **minute** level so make sure that your tests lasts longer than 1 minute
3. Each JMeter thread representing virtual user executes nested samplers upside down, when thread has nothing more to do it is being shut down. Make sure that you have enough job for threads and if not - make sure that you provide enough loops (see point 2 as well)
4. Constant Throughput Timer cannot kick off any new threads, it is capable of throttling (pausing) current active threads to limit load to throughput defined. So try increasing threads count.

For more information refer to [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) guide

You may also like to use [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) instead, it provides a little bit more flexibility than JMeter's CTT.

Comment: Iv'e changed the request per minute to 3000, but it seems that throughput has increased to 34, 45, ... fluctuating. Shouldn't it be constant 50. I actually need to explain the reason to my client.

Comment: Try increasing virtual users number. If it doesn't help - try increasing throughput timer value to i.e. 6000, if you will be still receiving throughput of ~40 it means that your application cannot respond any faster